# using set operator query to find the result of the given questions

Tags: sql, oracle, view, sqlplus

Using set operator display the DEPTNO,SUM(SAL) for each dept,  JOB,SUM(SAL) for each Job and Total Salary.

Using Set Operator display the JOB and Deptno  in employees working in deptno 20,10,30 in that order.

for first question my query is this:

```
select e.deptno,to_char(null),e.sum(sal),
from emp e
UNION
select d.deptno,d.job,d.sum(sal)
from emp d
group by deptno,job;
```

I have no idea how to do the second one.
SET opetator can be union,intersection,minus...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrasing of the first question is not 100% clear to me, but the query should be:

```
select deptno, '', sum(sal) from emp group by deptno
union
select deptno, job, sum(sal) from emp group by deptno, job
```

For the second question you can use `UNION` again. For example:

```
select job, deptno
from (
  select job, deptno, 2 as o from emp where deptno = 10
  union
  select job, deptno, 1 from emp where deptno = 20
  union 
  select job, deptno, 3 from emp where deptno = 30
) x
order by o
```

Comment: @MAYANKRAJ Please ask a new question if you more queries to write.